# Customize the user interface of sign in page with HTML templates in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: html, azure-ad-b2c

I want to add some warning text on sign in page only. There is sign up page as well. If I add this template in my azure ad b2c login, will it affect to sign in/sign up page? If yes, can someone tell me how can I show **some text on login page only**.
I'm following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow). The **unified sign up or sign** option making confusion that custom template will be applied to both. That should not happen in my case.

[image]

[image: Here there is an option in page layout unified sign up or sign in page.]

Comment: The page you linked to should have everything you need to know. You say it's "not yet clear" but you haven't told us which _specific_ part of it is unclear to you. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: I have updated the question with my specific requirement. I hope I have cleared myself now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some text on the login page only then you want to update the **Unified sign up or sign in page**, that won't affect your sign-up page.

To break down what each of the pages in that list do:

| Page | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Unified sign up or sign in page | This is the first page shown to users that allows them to sign-in with their local credentials, click a link to sign-up with local credentials, or choose to sign-in using a social/federated account. |
| Local account sign up page | This is the page shown to a user when they clicked the "sign-up" link on the unified sign-up/sign-in page. It prompts the user to enter their details and creates a new user record using local credentials in B2C. |
| Social account sign up page | This is the page shown to a user when they chose to sign-in using a social/federated account and they don't already have a user record in B2C. It prompts the user to enter their details and creates a new user record linked to the social/federated IdP's unique ID in B2C. |
| Multifactor authentication page | This is the page shown to a user when they need to perform MFA. |
| Blocked page due to Conditional Access | This is the page shown to a user when you're using [Conditional Access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/conditional-access-user-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow) and those policies indicate the user should be prevented from signing in. |
| Error page | This page is shown to users when an error occurs. |